# Sass and Compass setup on shared hosting

Tags: environment-variables, sass, compass-sass

I thought I'd try my hand at using SASS and am running into problems even getting it installed (on Bluehost shared hosting, it's not exactly the Ritz).

Here's what I get just checking to see if it installed:

```
username [~/public_html/sites/all/themes]# sass -v
Sass 3.2.7 (Media Mark)
username [~/public_html/sites/all/themes]# compass -v
Unable to load Sass. Please install it with one of the following commands:
gem install sass --pre
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sass (LoadError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/../lib/compass/dependencies.rb:6
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/../lib/compass.rb:5:in `require'
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/../lib/compass.rb:5
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/../lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/../lib/compass.rb:4
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `require'
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
from /home7/username/ruby/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19
```

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling in a different order, installing Sass with the --pre flag as suggested in the error message, installing compass on its own and letting sass get installed by compass, with the same result.

I haven't used these tools yet so I don't know what is supposed to happen, but I did have to update my $PATH to have the commands like "sass" work so I suspect compass is just not able to find sass or something. Posting in the hope that this is a no-brainer for someone with experience.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/365 and adding:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ruby/gems/bin
```

to my .bashrc resolved this exact error for me.